# Can I install and Activate Child theme years after having Parent theme only without harming my website?

Tags: parent-child

I am now using Parent theme and I am happy with it as I do not do any changes to theme files and I do not plan to do such changes. Also I've read about some drawbacks of installing a child theme - so I do not want to install it right now.

However, the question is - if in future I will want to do some changes in function php or other theme files and by that time my blog will already be quite big and with a lot of posts  - I can anyway install child theme any time in future without affecting my website? Am I right?

Or, I can then test child theme installation and activationin staging environment and if all ok - then push it to live. Is that correct?

As I've wrote, I do not see any necesity for child theme as of now, but I want to confirm that any time in future if I need it - then I can install  and activate it and that there is a way to do it without affecting my website.

Would appreciate if somebody can confirm this or express opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install the Child theme on your existing website without losing any changes. Basically, the Child theme will inherit all the styles of the Parent theme and you will be able to modify the Child theme files for any custom requirement.